# Spring cloud circuitbreaker: Create circuit breaker method creates a new Circuit breaker instead of returning existing one

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Spring's version of `Resilience4JCircuitBreaker` is a wrapper over `io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker` and also keeps an instance of the Circuitbreaker registry. I was hoping to use an already existing CircuitBreaker instance if it was already created. Looks like there is no way to do it if using Spring `Resilience4JCircuitBreaker`.

E.g. 
If using plain Resilience4J I can do something like

```
CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults(); // do it in the start of 
//the app.
in services. 
registry.circuitBreaker("context");
```

Seems like there is no way to do that with Resilience4JCircuitBreaker?

Comment: You could have a look at our own Resilience4j Spring Boot 2 starter -> https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

You can use Annotations and configure your instances via the application config file.

Demo -> https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot2-demo

Comment: Yes. Looks like that's what I'll have to do. I was hoping to use the Spring cloud implementation, but looks like I can't.

Comment: You can have a look at this blog post -> https://mromeh.com/2019/12/26/spring-cloud-gateway-with-resilience4j-circuit-breaker/

It shows how to combine Spring Cloud CircuitBreaker and our Spring Boot 2 Starter.